# Best way to find strings between two points

Tags: python, string

I know this is fairly basic, however I was wondering what the best way to find a string between two referenced points.

For example:

finding the string between 2 commas:

```
Hello, This is the string I want, blabla
```

My initial thought would be to create a list and have it do something like this:

```
stringtext= []
commacount = 0
word=""
for i in "Hello, This is the string I want, blabla":
    if i == "," and commacount != 1:
        commacount = 1
    elif i == "," and commacount == 1:
        commacount = 0
    if commacount == 1:
        stringtext.append(i)

print stringtext
for e in stringtext:
    word += str(e)

print word
```

However I was wondering if there was an easier way, or perhaps a way that is just simply different. Thankyou!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what `str.split(delimiter)` is for.
It returns a list, which you can do `[1]` or iterate through.

```
>>> foo = "Hello, this is the string I want, blabla"
>>> foo.split(',')
['Hello', ' this is the string I want', ' blabla']
>>> foo.split(',')[1]
' this is the string I want'
```

If you want to get rid of the leading space you can use `str.lstrip()`, or `str.strip()` to also remove trailing:

```
>>> foo.split(',')[1].lstrip()
'this is the string I want'
```

There's usually a built-in method available for something as simple as this in Python :-)
For more information check out [Built-in Types - String methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Comment: Thankyou, I knew I was doing it the hard way :I

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie It might be running through this with a string that doesn't contain any commas, and one that contains a single comma, and check the results are as you expect.

Comment: This is what I was expecting, well not exactly, but it is useful for what I am doing

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie If you want to remove the starting space, you could do something like this, printing from index 1 to end: `foo.split(',')[1][1:]`

Comment: or foo.split(',')[1].lstrip()

Comment: @LukaRahne Yeah, that's probably better. Updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to find the index of two references when those references doesn't need to be the same (as in two commas):

```
a = "Hello, This is the string I want, blabla"
i = a.find(",") + 1
j = a.find(",",i)
a[i:j]
>>> ' This is the string I want'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `re` - that makes it easier if you wish the start/end points to differ, or if you wanted more complicated criteria.

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Hello, This is the string I want, blabla"
>>> re.search(',(.*?),', s).group(1)
' This is the string I want'
```